# How to correctly receive a JSON response from AJAX (Javascript to PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, paypal

My script.php file sends a few variables (extracted from a HTML form) to my email.php file.

This file then saves all such variables to a MYSQL database, and in return also collects an "Order ID Number" (collected from mysql_insert_id), shown below:

```
$order_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

The $order_id is then passed **back** to script.php, which submits the product details to Paypal. Currently, I wish the Paypal's item name to read "Order ID: #$order_id".

However, I can't seem to send all the variables over to script.php, and then get the order ID back correctly.

I often receive a "Cannot read property 'order_id' of undefined" error in Google Chrome console, however now I'm triggering this piece of code from the JQuery 1.10.1 library (observed in Google Chrome console also)

```
// Uppercase the type
        s.type = s.type.toUpperCase();
```

Which then results in the following error: Uncaught Type Error: Object 1 has no method "toUpperCase".

Here's my code. I understand mysql is depreciated, but I'd like to get this implemented before I do any upgrades. ;)

**SCRIPT.PHP**

$('#submit').click(function(){
    // Perform checks to ensure all dropdown selections have been selected.
        // Validations have been successful, now populate variable portions of the paypal form
        $('#emailBuyer').val($('#email_paypal').val());

```
    var host     = $(location).attr('host');
    var protocol = $(location).attr('protocol');        
    var pathname = $(location).attr('pathname');

    var returnPath          = pathname.replace("removed","removed");
    var cancelReturnPath    = pathname.replace("removed","removed");
    var returnPathUrl       = protocol + "//" + host + returnPath + $('#email_paypal').val();
    var cancelReturnPathUrl = protocol + "//" + host + cancelReturnPath + $('#email_paypal').val();     

    $('#returnPath').val(returnPathUrl);        
    $('#cancelReturnPath').val(cancelReturnPathUrl);        

    // Send the email. It needs to have the async=false as the form is tried to redirect to paypal before the email is sent!
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
    $.get( controllerDir + 'email.php', {
    email: $('#email_paypal').val(),
    type: 1,
    question_one: $("#question_one option:selected").text(),
    question_two: $("#question_two option:selected").text(),
    question_three: $("#question_three option:selected").text(),
    question_four: $("#question_four option:selected").text(),
    question_five: $("#question_five option:selected").text(),
    question_six: $("#question_six option:selected").text(),
    question_seven: $("#question_seven option:selected").text(),
    question_eight: $("#question_eight option:selected").text(),
    question_nine: $("#question_nine option:selected").text(),
    question_ten: $("#question_ten option:selected").text(),
    amount: $('#amount').val(),
    shipping: $('#shipping').val(),
    total: $('#total').val(),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    var myData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(mydata['orderid']);
        if (myData.orderid == '0') {
            alert('FAILED');
            $('#item_name').val( order_id + 'FAILED' + '');
        } else {
        var order_id = myData.orderid;
        $('#item_name').val( order_id + 'SUCCESS' + '');
        }
    }
    });
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:true});
});
```

**EMAIL.PHP**

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html');
 //Define Variables
 //User ID for remote email server
    $user_id = "REMOVED";  // Reece
    $question_one = $_GET['question_one'];
    $q1 = ltrim($question_one, "0123456789., ");
    $question_two = $_GET['question_two'];
    $q2 = ltrim($question_two, "0123456789., ");
    $question_three = $_GET['question_three'];
    $q3 = ltrim($question_three, "0123456789., ");
    $question_four = $_GET['question_four'];
    $q4 = ltrim($question_four, "0123456789., ");
    $question_five = $_GET['question_five'];
    $q5 = ltrim($question_five, "0123456789., ");
    $question_six = $_GET['question_six'];
    $q6 = ltrim($question_six, "0123456789., ");
    $question_seven = $_GET['question_seven'];
    $q7 = ltrim($question_seven, "0123456789., ");
    $question_eight = $_GET['question_eight'];
    $q8 = ltrim($question_eight, "0123456789., ");
    $question_nine = $_GET['question_nine'];
    $q9 = ltrim($question_nine, "0123456789., ");
    $question_ten = $_GET['question_ten'];
    $q10 = ltrim($question_ten, "0123456789., ");
    $amount = $_GET['amount'];
    $shipping = $_GET['shipping'];
    $total = $_GET['total'];
    $type  = $_GET['type'];    
    $order = $_GET['order'];
    $date = date('m/d/Y');
    $email_paypal = $_GET['email'];

    // Upload to database first. All credentials are correct,
// as when the "success" part of the ajax call (script.php) is removed, everything is uploaded perfectly.
 mysql_connect("CORRECT WEBHOST", "CORRECT USER", "CORRECT PASS") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("CORRECT DB") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_query("CORRECT QUERY"); 
 $order_id = mysql_insert_id();

switch($type) {
        case "1" :
            $name     = "Order $order_id Placed on $date";
            $comments = "(UNPAID) $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, $q5, $q6, $q7, $q8, $q9, $q10"; 
            break;
        case "2" :
            $name     = "Order Paid on $date";
            $comments = "(PAID) $order";
            break;
        case "3" :
            $name     = "Order Cancelled on $date";
            $comments = "(CANCELLED) $order";
            break;          
        default :
            $name     = "$email_paypal $date";
            $comments = "Form Error. Unable to process email.";
    } 
    // Then send an email.

    $payload = "user_id=$user_id&form_id=2&name=$name&email=$email_paypal&comments=$comments";

    $curl_connection = curl_init("REMOVED");
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36");
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
    // NOTE: Error messages using an echo cannot be placed anywehere in this file. It distracts JSON and will make the Order ID variable unobtainable.
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("orderid" => "$order_id","email" => "$email_paypal"));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done it right. You do not have to set header to the `json` you are returning. If you set the `dataType` as `json` jQuery will expect the data as `json` and if the data returned by the php is not json it would be handled by the error function of `jQuery AJAX`.

You can replace this

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("orderid" => "$order_id","email" => "$email_paypal"));
```

By

```
die( json_encode(array("orderid" => "$order_id","email" => "$email_paypal")) );
```

Notice that I used `die` it is because I do not want anything else to run after I output `json`, extra `whitespaces` or other text that might get printed after the response can mess up the `json` response. So just to be safe.

hence you can skip this line as well in the `success function`

```
var myData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
```

it will be json

And this is not even in the question but just a sugestion that will reduce the lines of the codes

```
$question_one = $_GET['question_one'];
    $q1 = ltrim($question_one, "0123456789., ");
    $question_two = $_GET['question_two'];
    $q2 = ltrim($question_two, "0123456789., ");
    $question_three = $_GET['question_three'];
    $q3 = ltrim($question_three, "0123456789., ");
    $question_four = $_GET['question_four'];
    $q4 = ltrim($question_four, "0123456789., ");
    $question_five = $_GET['question_five'];
    $q5 = ltrim($question_five, "0123456789., ");
    $question_six = $_GET['question_six'];
    $q6 = ltrim($question_six, "0123456789., ");
    $question_seven = $_GET['question_seven'];
    $q7 = ltrim($question_seven, "0123456789., ");
    $question_eight = $_GET['question_eight'];
    $q8 = ltrim($question_eight, "0123456789., ");
    $question_nine = $_GET['question_nine'];
    $q9 = ltrim($question_nine, "0123456789., ");
    $question_ten = $_GET['question_ten'];
    $q10 = ltrim($question_ten, "0123456789., ");
```

this can be replaced by

but if it is possible to change the variables to question_1, question_2 and so on

I would do this in a loop

```
for( $i = 1 ; $i <=10;$i++ ) {
    $qVar = "q".$i;
    $questionVar = "question_" . $i;
    $$questionVar = $_GET[ $questionVar ];
    $$qVar = ltrim( $$questionVar, "0123456789., ");


}
```

This way you have you variable set up in four lines an you can access them as $q1, $q2..so on and $question_1, $question_2

But that's just me. I love loops :)

Comment: I think I'll save the use of loops until I've got this sorted ;)

It still doesn't work. I've updated the script.php code. I've noticed that the entire ajax call must be failing, as it isn't inserting into the database.

The insert works when I remove the "success: etc."...

Could it be that I am using $.get ? Rather than $.ajax?

Any help would be appreciated! ;)

Comment: you have user 1 as type parameter. `type: 1,` I have never used that. I am not even sure that it works. I think it should be `type : "post"` or `type : "get"`. try changing that.

Comment: I got confused with the code. instead of calling these twice `jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:true});` you could just make an ajax request with async:false.